# data visualization consoles with scala?

Tags: scala, ipython, visualization, jupyter

iPython/Jupyter + pandas + matplotlib provide an outstanding way to rapidly iterate and test analytics stuff within notebooks. I can write some code, build a table of data and plot it very easily.

I see that iPython/Jupyter supports scala, but I don't see a way of visualizing data. Is there support or other console-driven ways to easily plot data from a scala console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org) and [Beaker Notebook](http://beakernotebook.com), though I don't know if either is as programmable as matplotlib for visualization.